# Blazor WASM Client loads files twice

Tags: blazor, webassembly, .net-5

I create a new Blazor WASM Application in Visual Studio following these steps:

### Create a new WASM Application

1. Create a new Blazor WASM application.
2. Check ASP.NET core.
3. Check PWA.
4. Setup individual user accounts.

---

### Create a new database for the application

5. Open the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio
6. Update-Database.

---

### Run the new Application

7. Run the application.
8. Register a new user.
9. Log in with the new user.

---

### Inspect the page

10. Inspect the page in the browser.
11. Look at the Network tab.
12. Refresh the page.

---

### Output

[image]

---

### QUESTION: Why the double downloads? Can it be avoided?

You can see in the image above that many files are downloaded twice. The openid-configuration is even downloaded 4 times. And some of the requests are cancelled.

I am assuming that the index.html is downloaded first and then it goes to the login-callback which then redirects back. But I'm not sure if I understand and if the double downloads are absolutely necessary or can be solved somehow.

Comment: I can't comment yet, but can you update the question with a copy of your `wwwroot/index.html` file? Also, have you customized the Authentication flow in anyway?

Comment: You are running in debug mode, yes? This means the Webassemby `service-worker.js` is not caching anything. So every time the app verifies auth, for example, it has to download again from the server. Try it in release mode then see what happens.

Comment: The index.html is the one generated by Visual Studio. In release mode the same happens.